# Core plot create dynamic Y axis and display graph very clear

Tags: iphone, ios5, core-plot

How can i create dynamic y axis by only passing yMin and yMax graph plot automatically and display very clear.

For Example my Data is for Y axis 99.7, 99.3, 99.2, 99.0 ,100 .

so i want to y axis min start from 99 to 100 with 0.1 increment by which graph will display very clear.

my code snippet is bellow 
// 4 - Configre the y-axis

```
  y_monthly.title = lbl_M_HasDelay.text;
    y_monthly.labelAlignment = CPTAlignmentCenter;
    y_monthly.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
    y_monthly.titleOffset = -30.0f;
    y_monthly.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    y_monthly.majorGridLineStyle = gridLineStyle;
    y_monthly.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
    y_monthly.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
    y_monthly.labelOffset = 16.0f;
    y_monthly.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    y_monthly.majorTickLength = 4.0f;
    y_monthly.minorTickLength = 2.0f;
    y_monthly.tickDirection = CPTSignPositive;
    NSMutableSet *yLabels = [NSMutableSet set];
    NSMutableSet *yMajorLocations = [NSMutableSet set];
    NSMutableSet *yMinorLocations = [NSMutableSet set];
    float minorIncrement=month_MaxY1/10;
    float majorIncrement = minorIncrement*2;
    float yMax = month_MaxY1;

    for (float j = minorIncrement; j <= yMax; j += minorIncrement)
    {
        float mod = fmodf(j, majorIncrement);
        if (mod == 0) {
            CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]textStyle:y_monthly.labelTextStyle];
            [label setAlignment:CPTAlignmentTop];
            NSDecimal location = CPTDecimalFromFloat(j);
            label.tickLocation = location;
            label.offset = -y_monthly.majorTickLength - y_monthly.labelOffset;
            if (label) {
                [yLabels addObject:label];
            }
            [yMajorLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:location]];
        } else {

            [yMinorLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:CPTDecimalFromFloat(j)]];
        }
    }
    y_monthly.axisLabels = yLabels;
    y_monthly.majorTickLocations = yMajorLocations;
    y_monthly.minorTickLocations = yMinorLocations;
```

where month_MaxY1 =100 , and month_MinY1 =90.0.
Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the range of the y-axis using the plot space:

```
plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(99.0)
                                                length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(1.0)];
```

Label the axis:

```
y_monthly.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyFixedInterval;
y_monthly.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromDouble(0.1);
```

This will make ticks and labels every 0.1 unit along the y-axis. Set the `labelFormatter` and `labelTextStyle` to control the appearance of the labels.

Comment: Still i need to run loop to draw  major or miner interval  in y axis , which i did on above code . please help me  .

Comment: Thanks Erik...You are really great..:)

Comment: No, the fixed interval labeling policy will set the tick locations and the labels.

Comment: Please see this screenshot and pls tell me how can i draw x axis point with some distance from y axis ,now x axis override the y axis .                                                     https://www.dropbox.com/s/ltghvfjzbrmebc0/Screen%20Shot%202013-05-30%20at%201.32.23%20PM.png

Comment: And Also How can i show 4-5 digit after decimal in y Axis ..?

Comment: Create an `NSNumberFormatter` and configure it to give the desired number format. Set the axis `labelFormatter` to use this formatter.

Comment: Depending on the appearance you want, either set padding on the plot area frame or set the `visibleRange` of the axes. Take a look at the *Plot Gallery* example app, especially the "Control Chart" and "Real Time Plot" demos, for sample code.

Comment: Please tell me that how can make distance 'week-5' from y axis by which it show very clear not override . i am unable to find out the solution see this https://www.dropbox.com/s/ltghvfjzbrmebc0/Screen%20Shot%202013-05-30%20at%201.32.23%20PM.png.

Comment: Change the `location` of the plot space `xRange`.

Comment: see this link https://www.dropbox.com/s/czj7bjkjmos4lj7/Screen%20Shot%202013-06-04%20at%205.16.28%20PM.png & how can i make equal distance of tick in x axis between both y axis . please give me some idea.and x axis visible on between both y axis only.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your problem is to make your X axis to be displayed at the yMin position of your graph.
What you need to do is:

```
 x_axis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromDouble(yMin);
```

Comment: Martin Ullrich: It's not working as i want .Even i set the plot space from 99.0 to 100.0.